# Retornar dados do banco na tabela

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Bom dia, pessoas. Estou iniciando em PHP e fiz essa função abaixo com o objetivo de retornar os dados de duas tabelas do meu banco em uma table, só não consigo fazer funcionar de maneira alguma. Alguém pode me ajudar?

MODEL:

```
public static function listar(){
    $sql = "SELECT p.id, p.canhoto, m.nome, p.id_motorista FROM canhotos_saida p INNER JOIN motoristas m ON p.id_motorista = m.id";
    $conexao = new Conexao();
    $result = $conexao->consultar($sql);

    $lista = new ArrayObject();

    while ( list($id, $canhoto,$motorNome, $motorId) = mysqli_fetch_row( $result ) ){

        $driver = new Motoristas($motorNome, $motorId);

        $cs = new CanhotosSaida($id, $canhoto, $driver);

        $lista->append($cs);        
    }
    return $lista;
}
```

Código da table:

```
<?php
                include_once './model/clsCanhotosSaida.php';

                $lista = CanhotosSaida::listar();

                foreach ($lista as $nota) {

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '    <td>' .$nota->id. '</td> ';
                echo '    <td>' .$nota->canhoto. '</td> ';
                echo '    <td>' .$nota->motorista->nome. '</td> ';
                echo '</tr>';

                }

                ?>
```

Com esse código aí, me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\notas.php on line 39
```

A linha 39 é exatamente neste trecho do código da table:

```
echo '    <td>' .$nota->motorista->nome. '</td> ';
```

Detalhe: O nota->id e o canhoto estão aparecendo na table, só o nome do motorista que não...

Comment: tente algo como `$nota->['motorista']->nome`;

Comment: Desculpe pela demora. Infelizmente já fiz de tudo e ainda não consegui descobrir o que está errado...

Comment: dê um `var_dump($nota->motorista);` e mostre o resultado por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!!

tente dar um append tambem no objeto motorista, assim como você fez no outro:

```
$lista->append($cs);
```